# Thunderbird EWS Provider Share Folder ID

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, thunderbird, lightning

I am trying to get the lightning and exchange EWS provider add-ons for thunderbird to work together with viewing a shared folder.

I was able to get my personal calendar to load but I am at a loss as where to find the "share folder id" in outlook or the outlook web app.

I was able to get it working before but can't remember where I got lucky and found those ids.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the shared calendar to work by entering in the desired email address into the 'primary email address' field. The share folder id wasn't necessary.

Comment: If you are adding a team calendar and the team has been renamed you must enter the e-mail address that the team was created with.